# Php script executes but it doesnt display anything

Tags: php, android, sql-server, json

I have a php acript that has the goal of taking the data from a database in json format in order to display the said data on a android app.

I run the script on a server, but it doesnt return anything, no text, nothing, just a blank page. I dont know why even after looking a lot to the file.

The script:

```
    <?php

$serverName = "mssql3.gear.host";

/* Get UID and PWD from application-specific files.  */
$uid = '-----------';
$pwd = '-----------';
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                         "PWD"=>$pwd,
                         "Database"=>"programaplo");

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM Obras";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

if( $stmt === false ) {
     echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$json = array();

do {
     while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $json[] = $row;
   }
} while ( sqlsrv_next_result($stmt) );

/* Run the tabular results through json_encode() */
/* And ensure numbers don't get cast to trings */
print json_encode($json,<code> JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK</code>);
/* Free statement and connection resources. */
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Errors display turned on?

Comment: if you add some text before the opening PHP tag and run it, do you see that ?

Comment: I added error_reporting(1); No erros show.

Comment: Duane, nop,can´t see it.

Comment: After i did the change mentioned below i can see the text.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be the culprit - it gets you Parse error:

```
print json_encode($json,<code> JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK</code>);
```

Change it to:

```
print json_encode($json, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Hum, it did something, now i can see the text like one user above said to do, but it doesnt display anything else.

Comment: @BugDroid777 Which text are you referring to? The JSON-encoded string? Or some error message?

Comment: Someone said to add some random text before the php opening tag on the main post to check if i could see it, at first i couldn´t but i can see it now after yout change.

Comment: But i should be able to see either a error or the json, it remains a blank page

Comment: @BugDroid777 What happens when you add following code on the empty line after the opening tag: `var_dump(function_exists('sqlsrv_connect'));`. It should display something like `bool(true)` or `bool(false)`.

Comment: Hum.. it returned bool(false)

Comment: @BugDroid777: That would mean you don't have `sqlsrv` PHP extension installed on your webserver. See [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php) for more information.

Comment: Got it to work, that was the problem, thanks, i get the message "connected successfully" but it doesnt display the json string.